# PHP and MySQL encodings and strange signs

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I am receiving data from website in ISO-8859-2 from a website and than transform it to UTF-8 (also used as encoding in MySQL) and do some modifications and store data...

When I print data everything seems to be fine... when I store data to my table and print it from there everything is great... but when I compare newly received data and compare to those stored in mysql I always get no match although data is the same. So I checked DB .. when I open data in DB i see that there is a sign at the end or in the middle... Example: Ä, ‡, etc.

Any idea?

Update: I use InnoDB storage engine to enable transactions.. and exact DB encoding is UTF8_GENERAL_CI

Comment: Do you do the modification in PHP?  Is it possible to do such modification directly in MySQL instead?

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Hi, I tried to directly store to DB and than compare and it is the same :/

Comment: @deceze posted a link with some possible solution to your question.  Let us know if it helps.

Comment: Hi, yes currently I am trying to do this... don't worry will give feedback

Comment: Make sure that you do the encoding translation once you have the whole text, and not on individual parts.

Comment: @didierc I do that right after receiving data from file ...

Comment: Did you try your app without the translation part, to check if the problem was really in the translation?

Comment: @deceze that could work, but currently I have all fields to utf-8 and changing specific column to latin1 returns error...

Comment: I was thinking about using iconv (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) somehow

Comment: @M.V. Where does it say you should change anything to latin1? Most likely the problem is in the **connection encoding**. Just generally, check all the critical points mentioned in that article.

Comment: @deceze Yes I get it ... but this DB is filled with 7000000 + records and it works for those records ... I don't fell like messing with this :)

Comment: and there is a globally defined handler for DB

Comment: So basically the data in the database is already messed up because you inserted it using the wrong connection encoding?

Comment: No ... the rest of the data works fine ... it is a platform for insertign and editing data ... online for 6 years now ... and we are now planning to do some automatization ... It for UTF encoded sites and this is the first example of non UTF encoded data ... that is the problem...

Comment: One more thing ... ADODB5 for PHP is being used...

Comment: what are you using to compare the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got ISO-8859-2 input data ...

First I replaced strange sign by using:

```
$data = str_replace(chr(194), "", $data);

chr() uses ASCII code to search sign...
```

Next thing is to transform data to UTF-8 encoding

```
$data = iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $data);
```

I receive string with chars transformed, but again the same signs have somehow occured and so I did

```
$data = str_replace(chr(194), "", $data);
```

again ... After that I did:

```
$data = @iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $data);
```

That gave me cleaned UTF-8 even in case some strange chars were still included... @ at the beginning is to avoid throwing errors when there is a failure...

I believe this really is a specific case - I do with external data for a long time now and did not have a case like this one, but hopefully some day some one will needed it...

Thank you all for your help and cooperation... I wouldn't be able to solve this without community support! Thanks!